# How do I update_post_meta with a checkbox array?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, metadata, custom-wordpress-pages

How do I take all the checked options and fill my Custom Post Type Checkbox field?

Here is the form:

```
    <form action="#" method="post">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="column left labels">
<input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="Top (T1)"><label>Top (T1)</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="High (12)"><label>High (12)</label>
                </div>
              <div class="column left labels">
<input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="Mid (23)"><label>Mid (23)</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="Low (34)"><label>Low (34)</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column left labels">
<input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="Bottom (P4)"><label>Bottom (P4)</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="Other"><label>Other</label>
    </div>
    </div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I want to do this, but this doesn't work, it will only take the last value in the array:

```
__update_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'grips', $_POST['grips']);
```

I tried to loop through, but that will remove all the other checkmarks and leave only the last one added as well:

```
foreach($_POST['grips'] as $selected){
    echo $selected."</br>";
__update_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'grips', $selected);  
}
```

This is what I have in my Functions.php file:
I imagine I need another function for arrays since this one only updates single custom fields:

```
function __update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value = '' ) {
    if ( empty( $value ) OR ! $value )
    {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name );
    }
    elseif ( ! get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name ) )
    {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
    }
    else
    {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the Custom field I have set:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried printing the $_POST data? e.g. `var_dump($_POST); die;`. This will help you debug if the post data actually has all the values.

Comment: @LeviCole Yes I have, and the data is there: ["grips"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "Top (T1)" [1]=> string(8) "Low (34)" [2]=> string(11) "Bottom (P4)" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still want to learn how to do this with Meta data. But if you have ACF, the easy way to do this is via:

```
$field_key = "grips";
$value = $_POST['grips']; 
update_field( $field_key, $value, $the_post_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the following will solve your issue completely but it might help narrow down the cause.

Some alterations I suggest making to your custom function...

```php
<?php

function __update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value = '' ) {
    if ( empty( $value ) ) {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
    }
}
```

The middle step in your original question is redundant as WordPress takes care of this check with the `update_post_meta` function.

> If the meta field for the post does not exist, it will be added and its ID returned.

[Find out more here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

And to answer your query "I imagine I need another function for arrays since this one only updates single custom fields".

No. This is not needed as the `update_post_meta` function serializes values automatically.

Lastly, the `empty` function checks for empty strings so no need for `OR !$value`.

> The following values are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)

[Find out more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

Then the best thing you can do is to save the value as json format, you can use [maybe_serailize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_serialize/) and [maybe_unserialize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) to convert array to json and reverse.

First, you should assign a value on those checkbox that can be easily check/compared on with if state. Then pull the current value of that meta box and check if any of those checkboxes are already checked then you can assign them a checked attribute on load.

Here's an example code although UNTESTED. but this should give you an idea

Getting old values and assigning checked attributes on your input checkbox

```
$grips = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_grips', true); // Pull the value of meta key
$grips = $grips ? maybe_unserialize( $grips ) : false; // unserialize its value

//Create a function to check if value exist on the array and to assign checked attribute on input checkbox
function _check_grips( $array, $key ) {
    if ( !$array || !is_array( $array ) ) return;
    return in_array($key, $array) ? ' checked': '';
}
```

Then your HTML should look like this

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column left labels">
            <input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="1"<?php echo _check_grips('1'); ?>><label>Top (T1)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="2"<?php echo _check_grips('2'); ?>><label>High (12)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="column left labels">
            <input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="3"<?php echo _check_grips('3'); ?>><label>Mid (23)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="4"<?php echo _check_grips('4'); ?>><label>Low (34)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="column left labels">
            <input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="5"<?php echo _check_grips('5'); ?>><label>Bottom (P4)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="grips[]" value="6r"<?php echo _check_grips('6'); ?>><label>Other</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then to save the value, just do something like below

```
$grips = maybe_serialize( $_POST['grips'] );
__update_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_grips', $grips);
```